# How to properly display the json object?

Tags: php, json

I'm new to coding and I have a question

I would like to display correctly the output from json format with object name

```
header("Content-type:application/json"); 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;
$reader = new Reader('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-City.mmdb');
$reader2 = new Reader('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-ISP.mmdb');
$record = $reader->city("$ip");
$record2 = $reader2->isp("$ip");


echo json_encode($record->country->isoCode);
echo json_encode($record->city->name);
echo json_encode($record2->isp);
```

i would like the output in this format

```
{ "country":"UK","city":"London","isp":"Big Ben"}
```

instead of the actual code output

```
"UK""London""Big Ben"
```

it certainly has already discussed before but I don't know how what title I should search, I already open many many posts they all different.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array that has the structure you want and `json_encode` that.

```
$output = array( 
  "country" => $record->country->isoCode,
  "city" => $record->city->name,
  "isp" => $record2->isp
);

echo json_encode($output);
```